# Webdriver throwing timeout exceptions intermittently. The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nunit

Starting today my tests began failing sporadically across IE and Firefox. All failures are giving me this exception. This morning I was on `VS2013`, with Nunit `3.0.1`, `IEDriver 2.45.0.0`, `Selenium.Support` and `Selenium.WebDriver` 2.48.2. I thought it was because my packages were out of date and updated `Selenium.Support` and `Selenium.Webdriver` to `2.52.0`. The exception continued to intermittently plague my tests. The only thing that seems consistent with these exceptions is they are all being triggered by

```
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.someCondition(element));

    OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:7055/hub/session/e9b960bc-e750-41f1-93bf-7710bcfc1d5f/element timed out after 60 seconds.
  Source=WebDriver
  StackTrace:
       at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse(WebRequest request)
       at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
       at OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriverCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
       at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
       at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(String mechanism, String value)
       at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElementByCssSelector(String cssSelector)
       at OpenQA.Selenium.By.<>c__DisplayClass1e.<CssSelector>b__1c(ISearchContext context)
       at OpenQA.Selenium.By.FindElement(ISearchContext context)
       at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(By by)
       at OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.ExpectedConditions.<>c__DisplayClass13.<ElementIsVisible>b__12(IWebDriver driver)
       at OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.DefaultWait`1.Until[TResult](Func`2 condition)
       at POMAuctivaTest.AuctivaPageModels.BasePageModel.WaitForElementVisible(IWebDriver driver, By element) in c:\Users\jburns\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\POMAuctivaTest\POMAuctivaTest.AuctivaPageModels\BasePageModel.cs:line 125
       at POMAuctivaTest.AuctivaPageModels.ProfileManagmentPageModel.ChangeDateCreatedSortMostRecent() in c:\Users\jburns\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\POMAuctivaTest\POMAuctivaTest.AuctivaPageModels\ProfileManagmentPageModel.cs:line 66
       at POMAuctivaTest.TestSuite.ExistingUserTestSuite`1.CreateItemDetailProfileAndDelete() in c:\Users\jburns\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\POMAuctivaTest\POMAuctivaTest.TestSuite\ExistingUserTestSuite.cs:line 591
  InnerException: System.Net.WebException
       HResult=-2146233079
       Message=The operation has timed out
       Source=System
       StackTrace:
            at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
            at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse(WebRequest request)
       InnerException:
```

Any help would be amazing I am relatively new to webdriver and have a beginners level understanding of code concepts I am happy to provide extra information, this issue has already set me back a day and can't afford to lose more. Help me Stack Overflow you're my only hope.

Today 3/7 my tests are not hitting this exception as much as they were on Thursday (3/4) I have encountered it once this morning when my tests were waiting for a pop up window. Here is the line
`popupWindowHandle = finder.Click(NewListingPage.ImageSelectionPopupElement);`

@PankajDubey Here is a snippet of what all my wait methods look like. Am I using explicit waits here?

```
public void WaitForElementVisible(IWebDriver driver, By element)
{
    try
    {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(90));
        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(element));
    }
    catch (WebDriverTimeoutException)
    {
        TakeScreenshot(Driver);
        Console.Write("Test failed trying to wait for this element " + element.ToString() + " to be visible ");
    }
}
```

@Pankaj -- So in my `OneTimeSetup` I bumped the implicate wait time to 5 seconds as suggested. When I ran the tests they failed to locate elements that were on the screen. Test were repeatedly failing on the `ClickViewScheduled()` method.

```
        ListingDonePage.WaitForElementVisible(Driver, ListerDonePageModel.ViewScheduledSelector);
        var ScheduledListingPage = ListingDonePage.ClickViewScheduled();
```

Here is the definition of `ClickViewScheduled()`. This is odd to me as in the previous line it waits for the visibility of the element, using the wait method I posted above this. So it 'found' the element in that line and then could not find it for the click?

```
    public ScheduledListingsPageModel ClickViewScheduled()
    {
        ViewScheduledElement.Click();
        return new ScheduledListingsPageModel(Driver);
    }
```

Comment: I've seen this issue when my tests have "hammered" the webdriver too hard.  Don't know if that's your issue.  I think I've also seen it when I spin off asynchronous webdriver commands. In other words the webdriver is usually knocked silly.

Answer (score 0):

use implicit wait to handle this where you have declared the web-driver instance instead of explicit time (wait statement) for each scenarios.

`driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));`

If it doesn't work, please enter the code snippet where you are facing this exception for more clarification.

Comment: Now I havent read up on the documentation, but I have been reading on here and other sources that you should stay away from implicit waits? and instead use explicit waits with expected conditions That is the implementation I have in my test. Might I ask why you suggest implicit vs explicit?

Comment: I edited question to include snippet of wait methods.

Comment: I am struggling to add properly formatted code to a comment so I am editing my original description to include what happened when I tried your implicit wait solution.